# How do I convert the Redis string object data?

Tags: node.js, redis

```
redisClient.lpush(msg.roomId,`avatar:${msg.avatar},name:${msg.name},msg:${msg.msg}`)

 key 0 value avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg
 key 1 value avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test2,msg:testmsg
 key 2 value avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test,msg:testmsg
```

The string saved in the above format and stored in the redis.

The string was received after running lrange, but could not be replaced with an object type. This is the string data I received.

```
[
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg',
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test2,msg:testmsg',
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test3,msg:testmsg'
]
```

How can I convert objects? And is there a better way to save objects in Redis?

Comment: What object type? You inserted a string in redis list and you got redis list with strings with LRANGE command. What is the issue?

Comment: [
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg',
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test2,msg:testmsg',
  'avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test3,msg:testmsg'
]                                                                                                                             want to change this form to object type for use in client.

Comment: For example
[
 { avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg},
  { avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg},
 { avatar:avatar_1612108434326,name:test1,msg:testmsg}
]

Comment: try with `set ` prepare the object and execute set,

Comment: In 'avatar_1612108434326', is the '1612108434326' part unique for each entry? Or there can be more than one 'avatar_1612108434326' as mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are unique, then instead of using Redis LIST, you can use Redis Hashes, with 'avatar_1612108434326' as the name of the hash and the rest of the data as the key value pair inside the hash.
As an example, I am setting 3 hashes manually using redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset avatar_1612108434326 name test1 msg testmsg
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset avatar_1612108434327 name test2 msg testmsg
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset avatar_1612108434328 name test3 msg testmsg
(integer) 2
```

Now from your nodejs client, you can use scan method to scan all the keys with pattern avatar_* and then hgetall to get all the elements inside the hash as shown below:

Code:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

var scanned_stream = redis.scanStream({
  match: 'avatar_*'
});

scanned_stream.on('data', function (keys) {
    
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        redis.hgetall(keys[i], (err, result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }); 
    }
});
```

Output:

```
$ node scan_pattern.js 
{ name: 'test3', msg: 'testmsg' }
{ name: 'test1', msg: 'testmsg' }
{ name: 'test2', msg: 'testmsg' }
```